# Groovy/Grails No signature of method

Tags: grails, groovy

Executing (in console) from a grails project:

`import vine.*
import grails.converters.JSON
s = Stem.makeStem([name: "nameValue", description: "Description value"], "24601")
println s as JSON`

Generates:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: vine.Stem.makeStem() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String) values: [[name:nameValue, description:Description value], BR-459]
>   Possible solutions: makeStem(java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)

The method definition:

```
def makeStem( LinkedHashMap h, String owner)
{
    def s
    if ( h.name && h.description ) {
       s  = new Stem(h)
       def ra = new RoleAssignment(peoples: owner)
       s.addRole(ra)
    }
    return s
}
```

I originally had the def with Map h, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be calling that statically, but it's not static...  Try changing `def makeStem` to `static makeStem`

Comment: is Stem a service class?

Comment: Stem is a Domain, makeStem is a method of Stem.

Comment: If Stem is a Domain, then you need to either instantiate the Stem class or mark the makeStem class static.

Comment: Making makeStem static worked.  The error message was a little confusing (I guess you've seen it before.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Stem is a service class.

You can do the following in Grails console

```
import vine.*
import grails.converters.JSON
def stem= ctx.stem
s = stem.makeStem([name: "nameValue", description: "Description value"], "24601")
println s as JSON
```

Assuming Stem is a domain class,

```
static makeStem( LinkedHashMap h, String owner)   // convert it to a static method
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I should have said that Stem is  a Domain and makeStem is a method of Stem.